# expressions must have consistent types

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

i have this error while running a terraform plan :

```
│   on cluster/main.tf line 8, in locals:
│    8:   database = var.enabled ? var.config.database.mydb : {}
│     ├────────────────
│     │ var.config.database.mydb is object with 8 attributes
│     │ var.enabled is false
│ 
│ The true and false result expressions must have consistent types. The given
│ expressions are object and object, respectively.
```

enabled is defined this way :

```
variable "enabled" {
  type = bool
}
```

and mydb is the app's database.

couldn't figure out a way and the solutions proposed on other questions (by using tomap) give me another problem later

Comment: The error message states that your `var.config.database.mydb` is type inconsistent with the empty Map constructor `{}`. We would need to see that variable declaration instead of `enabled`.

Answer (score 3):

Terraform reported this error because `{}` doesn't have the same type as `var.config.database.mydb`. That variable apparently has an object type with eight attributes, so Terraform is correct that an object with no attributes isn't compatible with it.

The two main options to make this pass typechecking would be to use a consistently-typed fallback value, or to use `null` to explicitly represent the absence of this value when it's disabled.

---

I can't show a full example of the first option because your question didn't include the type constraint of `var.config`, but assuming that this object's eight attributes are just called attr1 through attr8 then the idea would be to write suitable placeholder values that are of the same types as the provided attributes would have:

```
  database = var.enabled ? var.config.database.mydb : {
    attr1 = false
    attr2 = 0
    attr3 = ""
    attr4 = null
    attr5 = toset([])
    attr6 = "placeholder"
    attr7 = "..."
    attr8 = 15
  }
```

---

The second option is simpler in your local variable expression itself:

```
  database = var.enabled ? var.config.database.mydb : null
```

`null` is convertible to any type and so the above should be considered valid by Terraform, but it does mean that any expression elsewhere in your module which refers to `local.database` must be written to handle the case where it is `null` as well as the case where it's set.

One way to do that is to make the references use [the `try` function](https://www.terraform.io/language/functions/try) to handle the error that would normally occur when accessing an attribute on `null` and to substitute a fallback value instead. For example:

```
  example = try(local.database.attr6, "placeholder")
```

Notice that again I provided a valid fallback value for whatever this `example` argument is, which means this would get the same result as the other option of assigning a non-null default value to `local.database`. The key difference here is that each reference to `local.database` can potentially have a *different* fallback value if you need to, whereas the first option would make the fallback value consistent across all references to `local.database`.